# Div under a div without height

Tags: html, css

If I have two divs, and in the first div there is some image tag with a width of 100% so it fits the screen like

```
<div id="first"><img src="" width="100%"></div>
<div id="second">Some Text</div>
```

How do I make it so `#second` is positioned under `#first`? It should work by default, but because the height of `#first` is not set, `#second` is being positioned at the same place `#first` is positioned.

Comment: "It should work by default" --> http://jsfiddle.net/NSZUa/

Comment: we really need to see the CSS to know whats wrong.  Are you positioning them using CSS?

Comment: are you sure that you don't have any css rule applied to `#first` or `#second` probably you set one of them to `position: absolute`

Comment: @t.niese i set `#first` to `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed should work by default.

You either

- Made your divs `inline-block`s
- Set their `position` to `absolute`
- `float`ing them to the `left`

Most likely it's the second scenario. Set their `position` to `static`.

Comment: OK, I am having a problem. If I use `position: static`, I can't position it using `left, top` etc anymore. Is there an alternative? I tried margin but if I do that the image does not fit the whole screen any more

Comment: Try `position: relative`, then `left` will change it's position relative to its original position

Comment: that gives me the same problem I had when using `margin`. I want the image to fill the entire width of the screen, but now there is empty space on the right

Comment: I think you need to rethink your structure. If you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) explaining your situation, it could be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Floating and/or giving the first an automatic height might do the trick:

```
#first { 
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden; /* or height: auto perhaps*/
}

#second {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: too late, problem solved while I typed :)

We really need to see your CSS, but compare your values to these; if they're set to anything else, that may be the problem.

```
#first {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    position: relative; /* or possibly position: static; */
}

#second {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    position: relative; /* or possibly position: static; */
}
```

What about the image? Any CSS rules assigned to that? Is there a div around these two divs with a max-height?